# Can I omit "of it" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

> "So in the end I decided to keep this *hobby* to myself, as well as
>   the information I'd gathered about it. By then, I had a massive
>   amount **of it**, enough to fill a closet.

Can I remove the "of it"? Will the sentence still be grammatical?

Comment: You can remove the "of it," and the sentence will be just as mediocre as before.

Comment: @J.R.♦ Why mediocre? What would you suggest to improve it?

Comment: Sorry, alex, that would be proofreading...

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's still grammatical, but both ways it has a slightly strange ring about it, in my opinion.  It doesn't feel obvious what the "it" (which you have massive amounts of) is.

Comment: Welcome to the site Mark! The answer part is reserved for the answers to the questions. As ELL isn't a forum, requesting clarification is with commenting on posts. You can comment on your posts, and when you get 50 rep, you can comment on any post.

Comment: Fair enough. My basic, straight, answer to the question is in the first sentence.  The second sentence is indeed more of a comment but I didn't think it stood very well on its own, out of the context of my answer.

Comment: Hmm, well. I'd delete the comment-like parts and I'd get a *yes*, accordingly. I don't think StackExchange encourages *Yes*'s as appropriate answers.

Comment: If it's a yes/no question (and it is), I think "yes" is an appropriate answer, is it not?

Comment: Alexchenco: I'm confused by why you put *hobby in italics*.  Is the "it" you're referring to (of which you had a massive amount) the information, or something else?

Comment: But with that logic, half of the questions in SE would be answered with **yes** or **no**, or their capitalized formats.

Comment: I don't think we're getting anywhere here. If the answer is "yes" or "no", what more do you want?

Comment: Mark take a look at [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269297/why-was-this-answer-deleted). Also, this discussion is getting lengthy. Please come to ELL's chat if you want further discussion.

Comment: I think this would be a good answer if it were a little more verbose. I see the ambiguity of "it" that you mentioned, but it might help someone less familiar with English if you explained a little more why the second sentence is awkward. Also, I'm not sure how many learners understand that "IMO" means "in my opinion".